# Cannot access memory when debugging xv6 user program using gdb

Tags: gdb, riscv, xv6

I am currently self-studying 2020 MIT 6.S081: Operating System Engineering https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2020/schedule.html. I have followed all the steps for MAC OS to set up the environment correctly.
When I launched gdb and qemu together, I was able to break points normally when debugging the kernel executable.

[image]

However, when I attempted to do the same thing for the user executables, I was unable to break any points with the error:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x...
```

[image]

It turned out I can set break points for some particular lines, but when I hit continue, another error has shown in the screenshot above.

Any way to get around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also self-studying 6.S081 and have had the same issue. I solved this just now so try this.

In Makefile, add `-gdwarf-2` option to `CFLAGS` variable:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -gdwarf-2
```

In my Makefile it's on line 94, and I didn't change other options.

I find this solution from here:

- [http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~bjhua/courses/ats/2014/hw/hw-interface.html](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ebjhua/courses/ats/2014/hw/hw-interface.html) (search 'error reading variable' in the page)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/RISCV/comments/plgwyk/comment/hcalnf1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

and one more thing: If you successfully solve the problem with this but fail to `watch` variables in gdb, try chainging `-O` option for `CFLAGS` to `-O0`. It would prevent your code from being optimized ([ref](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/1213-print-optimized-out-value-in-gdb#:%7E:text=The%20message,basis%2C%20or%20program%2Dwide.)). (For me, this doesn't work. my code start to stuck frequently after changing this option so I just quit watching variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out whether your gdb has warned you can't use file .gdbinit to start gdb? If not, you can simply add a line to .gdbinit: `set riscv use-compressed-breakpoints yes`,like this:

```
set confirm off
set architecture riscv:rv64
target remote 127.0.0.1:26000
symbol-file kernel/kernel
set disassemble-next-line auto
set riscv use-compressed-breakpoints yes
```

then use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` to start gdb.You will see it work well.
But if you have the warning, then you should use
`riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb -iex 'add-auto-load-safe-path .'` to start gdb additionally.

Comment: It doesn't help me actually. Do you have any other tips for that? @Kaiyu Yang

Comment: @Roeniss Sorry, it has been a long time since I last coded xv6. You may get some useful help from this: https://piazza.com/mooc_self-learning_university/fall2020/6s081. About the cannot access the memory problem, you can also refer to this: https://piazza.com/class/kgkxf1hjf3kw7?cid=12. Good luck!